# Oauth, Devise and Mongoid session cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, oauth, devise, mongoid

Trying to login with another account, i found that on login not asks again for a gmail account.

My action/method is this

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  def destroy
    super
    cookies.delete :_myapp_session
  end
end
```

It comes here as **delete method** in `routes.rb`

When i delete all cookies from browser, i can login watching the gmail page.
If i login with another account stills loading the data from the other account.

I use Devise with omniauth and **Mongoid instead ActiveRecord**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Problem was that user not created before as properly fields needed on
>   model like **uid** and **provider**